# A specific app works fine with tablet owner account, but crashes for other users

Tags: force-close, multi-user

I've played Modern War on the owner account on my Nexus 7. It opens and works fine. But when I go to another user account and try to open the app it goes halfway through the upload then Force Closes. I've done it with two more user accounts and the same thing happens. The only account where opens is the owner account. Does anybody know why this is happening? (I figured if it was separate space and storage it should be like having two phones.)

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this issue on my Nexus 7, too.  Any account other than the admin causes my app to crash.

What I've discovered so far is that with my app, there is a permissions issue when it tries to access the game database. I receive this:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException... open failed: EACCESS (Permission denied).

That database is stored in the `data/data/{package name}` directory... So it looks like secondary users may not have rights to access the `data/` directory.  I'll try to remember to let you know if I find a resolution or find anything else that is useful.

Answer (score -1):

Is the game download and installed from a valid source or it's a cracked game. If you have installed it from a valid source try reinstalling it.

Comment: I've down loaded it from Google play' and other sources. I've restored tablet to start over and started by installing only on user and it still doesn't open. The user portion is my sons area and he likes the game but its no good when he can't play it also. Just not sure what else to do about it. Thought maybe it was in the settings but if users are granted all permission then they should have all the same programs to be able to run the game