# Making apps installed by Owner visible to other users/profiles

Tags: applications, android-10, multi-user, restricted-profiles, android-11

So, as you might know, Android 10 supports Multi-User feature (for reference - [this thing](https://www.howtogeek.com/333484/how-to-set-up-multiple-user-profiles-on-android))

I have some apps from F-Droid, installed while on Owner profile. But most of the apps are only visible to Owner (I suppose those are User apps, as the universally visible are System apps).

But how can I make some of these apps visible to other profiles so I can use them with all the features provided with separate user accounts (e.g. compartmentalized app data)? Preferably using only one device, without `ADB` connection to PC, and without re-installation.

There are similar questions on this topic ([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/if-the-owner-installs-an-app-can-a-secondary-profile-use-it), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51132/a-specific-app-works-fine-with-tablet-owner-account-but-crashes-for-other-users), [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/is-it-possible-to-make-admin-user-apps-available-on-other-user-accounts)), but the answers are outdated. The newest one is 7 years ago.

Comment: How to install apps to secondary user account: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/119312/218526. How to share files between user accounts and profiles: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221593/218526. Can apps share data between profiles: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526

Comment: @IrfanLatif are there any ways to do it without `ADB` connection to PC and/or app re-installation?

Comment: No, or at least not in my knowledge.

Comment: @IrfanLatif what about moving app files from `/data/app` to `/system/priv-app`? It could be done from custom recovery, e.g `TWRP`. Does it have any drawbacks and/or additional actions required?

Comment: I won't go that hard way to achieve something simple. But you can try it.

Comment: @IrfanLatif how does Google Play manage user access to apps btw? With CMOD and masks? Or puts app files in certain folders?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. But Google Play doesn't share data between users and profiles. Each user/profile has it's own Google account.

Comment: @IrfanLatif so the apps should be individually installed for each user?

Comment: Sir the whole purpose of users/profiles is isolation. With every new release Android is tightening the restrictions on any possible interactions between users/profiles. If the data and apps are sharable the whole thing is pointless. Isolation is the whole purpose of multiple users, even on desktop OSes. I suggest you again to read my answer to the third question linked above.

Comment: @IrfanLatif isolation of data is literally why I want to use Android Multiple Users feature. But I also want apps to be updated and executables to be the same for each User using them. And to save space on the drive.

Comment: Apps are only installed to `/system/app` or `/data/app`. Only their data directories are duplicated, not APK files.